# Fourier series for a piecewise function

Tags: fourier-series

I'm working on a problem concerning fourier, but got stuck at two points.
 Here is the question:

3)
 Find the fourier series of the function $$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $|x|<1$ } \\
0, & \text{if $1\leq|x|<2$ }
\end{cases}$$

Added is the solution:

[image: The solution]

In the first step I dont get why they use $f(x)=0$ if $-2\leq x\leq -1$ and $f(x)=0$ if $1\leq x\leq 2$ 
 Why smaller/bigger or $\mathbf {equal}$ to $2$  and $-2$? Since in the problem it says $|x|<2$

Then in the final step after the coefficients are calculated I don't understand how they get to this fourier series, normally you use this rule of $a_0+ \sum a_ncos(\frac{n\pi x}{L})+ b_n sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})$ but here in the final answer there are no cosines.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: $[-2,2]$ is the same as $(-2,2)$ when integrating a piecewise continuous function

Comment: A sine is just a cosine shifted by $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Your function is even so it a sum of cosines, but you can write it as a sum of sines with suitable phase shifts if you like. This has only been done to create a clean looking infinite sum, but there really is no need for it.